# Can an operator have Exp(z) as its characteristic "polynomial"?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, rt.representation-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $\mathcal{H}$ be a Hilbert space, and let $T: \mathcal{H} \rightarrow \mathcal{H}$ be a trace-class operator.  Define
$$ f_T(z) = \sum_{i=0}^\infty \mbox{Tr}(\wedge^k T) \cdot z^k, $$

the ordinary generating function for traces of exterior powers of $T$.  Expressed another way,

$$ f_T(z) = \mbox{Det}(I + zT) $$

where $\mbox{Det}$ is the Fredholm determinant.  This function is entire, and can be considered a generalization of the characteristic polynomial.

I am wondering if 
$$f_T(z) = e^z $$
for some natural choice of $T$ on some nice incarnation of Hilbert space.

The motivation for this problem comes from representation theory, where finite minors of such a $T$ provide a formula for dimensions of irreps of $S_n$, the symmetric group on $n$ letters.

--edit--

In order to provide slightly more background on the sort of application I have in mind, here is an attractive identity which might pique your interest:

If $\beta : \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is any function, define $$\gamma(z) = \frac{1}{\Gamma(z+1)}, \hspace{.4in} \delta(z) = \frac{\beta(z)}{\Gamma(z+1)}$$
Now

$$
\left|
\begin{pmatrix} 
\gamma(3) & \gamma(4) & \gamma(5) \\\\
\gamma(-1) & \gamma(0) & \gamma(1) \\\\
\gamma(-2) & \gamma(-1) & \gamma(0)
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} 
\delta(3) & \delta(4) & \delta(5)\\\\
\delta(-1) & \delta(0) & \delta(1)\\\\
\delta(-2) & \delta(-1) & \delta(0)
\end{pmatrix}
\right|
+ $$
$$
\left|
\begin{pmatrix} 
\gamma(2) & \gamma(3) & \gamma(4) \\\\
\gamma(0) & \gamma(1) & \gamma(2) \\\\
\gamma(-2) & \gamma(-1) & \gamma(0)
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} 
\delta(2) & \delta(3) & \delta(4)\\\\
\delta(0) & \delta(1) & \delta(2)\\\\
\delta(-2) & \delta(-1) & \delta(0)
\end{pmatrix}
\right|
+ $$
$$
\left|
\begin{pmatrix} 
\gamma(1) & \gamma(2) & \gamma(3) \\\\
\gamma(0) & \gamma(1) & \gamma(2) \\\\
\gamma(-1) & \gamma(0) & \gamma(1)
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} 
\delta(1) & \delta(2) & \delta(3)\\\\
\delta(0) & \delta(1) & \delta(2)\\\\
\delta(-1) & \delta(0) & \delta(1)
\end{pmatrix}
\right| = \frac{\delta(1)^3}{3!}
$$

Comment: Since $e^z$ has no zeros, it seems that such a $T$ either cannot exist or must be extremely weird to begin with.

Comment: Well, it does have zeros...

Comment: @András Bátkai What do you mean?

Comment: @ARupinski: wouldn't the Fredholm determinant of a quasinilpotent trace-class operator be an entire, nowhere-vanishing function?

Comment: I think it's true that $f(z)={\rm Det}(I+zT)$ can be written as $\prod\_n(1+z\lambda\_n)$ where $\lambda\_n$ are the eigenvalues of $T$ (I just say *think*, because I haven't really looked at Fredholm determinants before). Then, if $f$ is nowhere zero, we have $\lambda\_n=0$, so $f(z)=1$. Therefore, the answer to the question is no.

Comment: @George Lowther I think such an expression is true when $T$ can be diagonalized (by the spectral theorem, for instance).  It seems less likely in general.

Comment: @John: I think it is true in general. Diagonalization is not necessary. You can still decompose $\mathcal{H}$ into the orthonal sum of a sequence of finite dimensional subspaces preserved by $T$, and the orthogonal complement $V$ on which $T$ (followed by orthogonal projection onto $V$) is quasinilpotent. So, by Yemon Choi's comment below, $T$ projected onto $V$ is traceless, as are its powers. So, the calculation of the determinant reduces to the increasing limit over finite dimensional spaces, and the product follows from the finite dimensional case.

Comment: @John: See my answer. I include a reference for the product expansion.

Comment: Hi John, have you seen my recent question? http://mathoverflow.net/questions/196030/where-does-this-identity-involving-sums-of-hankel-like-determinants-over-partiti

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here's a proof that $\exp(z)$ is not a characteristic function using the product expansion for the determinant, which is essentially equivalent to Lidskii's theorem stating that the trace of a trace class operator is the sum of its eigenvalues.

> If $T$ is a trace class operator on a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$ with eigenvalues $\lambda_n$ (counted up to algebraic multiplicity), then $\sum_n\vert\lambda_n\vert < \infty$ and
>   $$
> {\rm det}(1+zT)\equiv\sum_{k=0}^\infty{\rm Tr}(\Lambda^kT)z^k=\prod_n(1+z\lambda_n)
> $$
>   for all $z\in\mathbb{C}$.

See [*Trace Ideals and Their Applications*, Theorem 3.7](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=-1snx2pn59cC&lpg=PA32&ots=tzxSfOUAhs&dq=%252B%2522trace%2520class%2522%2520%252Beigenvalues%2520%252Blidskii&pg=PA35#v=onepage&q=Theorem%25203.7&f=false). Actually, they use this result to prove Lidskii's theorem, that ${\rm Tr}(T)=\sum_n\lambda_n$.

Then, ${\rm det}(1+zT)$ cannot be equal to $\exp(z)$ everywhere. This is because $\exp$ has no zeros, so $\lambda_n$ would have to be all zero, giving ${\rm det}(1+zT)=1$.

Answer (score 7):

This is not an answer, but just a sketch of a possible answer; I think the answer is *no*.
For $T$ as desired, consider $Det(I-z^2T^2)=Det(I-zT)\cdot Det(I+zT)=e^{-z}\cdot e^z\equiv 1$. Considering the Taylor expansion of this function, one can conclude that $Trace(T^{2n})=0$ for any natural $n$. I think this yields $T^2=0$, and then the claim follows.

Actually, I am not sure if such determinant may have positive exponential type - this could be another approach.

Comment: If $T^2$ is a quasinilpotent trace class operator, then it has trace zero (Lidskii). So all powers of $T^2$ have trace zero. Does this imply that $\Tr(\wedge^{2k} T) \neq 1/(2k!)$?

Comment: If so, maybe my first argument that $T^2=0$ is wrong; I got it from the finite-dimensional situation.

Comment: Don't you mean ${\rm Trace}(\Lambda^nT^2)=0$?

Comment: or are these the same thing?

Comment: If you consider the Taylor expansion in the finite-dimensional case in terms of eigenvalues, the $n$-th coefficient will be a function of degree $n$ with a symmetrical expression for eigenvalues. This means that $Trace T^{2n}=0$.

Comment: Ok. That proves that $T$ is quasinilpotent (all eigenvalues are zero). Then, I think, $\Lambda^nT$ is also quasinilpotent and ${\rm Det}(I+zT)=1$, giving a negative result to the question.